# How to assign gear loadouts to hot keys for quick changing?

Tags: assassins-creed-odyssey

I use at least two gear loadouts in the game actively - one for sneaking around and killing like a hitman (assassin), other for combat (warrior set). Because the first one is primary and from time to time my assassination escalates into hard combat I often change my gear loadout while starting to fight. But it is pretty annoying to go every time into inventory menu and perform switch over there (and do the reverse after combat is finished).

Therefore my question:
Is it possible to assign gear loadouts to hot keys, so you can switch loadouts quickly without going into inventory screen?

Comment: I agree this is annoying. I made up some head cannon that helps me. I think that I like to go into a situation dressed for whatever it is i'm gonna do. Stealth or combat. Then if I get caught while stealthing then just as in real life I'm stuck with what I've got until I can get away. It'd be nice to have a hotkey that lets you swap these out without having to go to the menu, but for me this at least helps me to enjoy the game a little more.